# Why do I get an error upon entering user into a database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm teaching myself `Mongodb`.  At first, I ran `npm install --save mongoose uuid` in `Terminal` to start things off.  The goal of my program is to store a user in the database.

In `Terminal`, after running `node index.js` I want it to say:

```
About to save!
Saved!
```

But what I'm seeing in `Terminal` is (below):

Here's `index.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uuid = require('uuid');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/* New code from suggested website in error */ 

var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:testMongo/testMongo', {
    useMongoClient: true,
});

promise.then(function(db) {

    db.model();
    connection.openUri('mongodb://localhost:testMongo/testMongo', { /* options */ });


var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {type: String},

    todos: [
        {
            text: {type: String}
        }
    ]
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    console.log("About to save!");
    var user = this;
    user.password = uuid.v4();
    next();
});

 var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
 var email = 'test@test.com';

// var user = new User({
//     email: email
// });
//
// user.save(function(err) {
//     if(err) {
//         return console.log(err);
//     } else {
//         return console.log("User was saved!");
//     }
// })
//
// console.log("Outside of callback!");

var text = "This is a todo.";

User.findOne({email: email}, function(user, err) {
   if(err) {
       return console.log(err);
   }

   if(!user) {
       return console.log("Couldn't find user!");
   }

   var count = user.todos.push({
       text: text
   });

   console.log(count);

   user.save(function(err){
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          console.log("Saved!");
      }
   });
});
```

Error in `Terminal`:

```
(node:14312) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
{ _id: 595fe7c14a9810330c75aacc,
  password: '297d5907-d9d7-49ef-800c-97a56aa395f7',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  __v: 0,
  todos: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. It clearly says it's a warning: `DeprecationWarning`.
Also the message gives you a link to resolve the warning: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client

Comment: I edited my code in my original post.  I've added some new code in reference to the website in the error but I still don't think I'm using it right because it isn't working.